# Unix domain socket permissions between Ubuntu Lucid and Trusty

Tags: linux, sockets, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-14.04, unix-socket

I have a web application which I am migrating from Ubuntu Lucid to Trusty. The app communicates w/ Nginx via unix domain sockets (created w/ a umask of `000`). On Lucid, I've had no problem with this setup. However, on Trusty, using the same permissions setup, Nginx gives me the following error:

```
*51 connect() to unix:/opt/run/skyhook/skyhook.socket failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client
```

Examining the permissions on both servers, I see this:

On lucid:

```
$ sudo ls -lh /opt/run/skyhook/skyhook.socket
srwxrwxrwx 1 skyhook skyhook 0 2014-08-21 17:09 /opt/run/skyhook/skyhook.socket
$ sudo sudo -u www-data ls -lh /opt/run/skyhook/skyhook.socket
srwxrwxrwx 1 skyhook skyhook 0 2014-08-21 17:09 /opt/run/skyhook/skyhook.socket
```

On trusty:

```
$ sudo ls -lh /opt/run/skyhook/skyhook.socket
srwxrwxrwx 1 skyhook skyhook 0 Nov  4 15:36 /opt/run/skyhook/skyhook.socket
$ sudo sudo -u www-data ls -lh /opt/run/skyhook/skyhook.socket
ls: cannot access /opt/run/skyhook/skyhook.socket: Permission denied
```

Same permissions on both servers, different results. Nginx runs as www-data on Ubuntu. With the `777` permissions, I would expect www-data to be able to interact with the socket, but it can't. What is going on?

**UPDATE:**

The permissions of `/opt/run/skyhook` are the same on both lucid and trusty:

```
$ sudo ls -lhd /opt/run/skyhook
drwxrwx--- 2 skyhook skyhook 4.0K Nov  4 15:36 /opt/run/skyhook
```

For `/opt/run` the differences are minor. On lucid:

```
$ sudo ls -lhd /opt/run/
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data www-data 4.0K 2014-01-27 18:11 /opt/run/
```

On trusty:

```
$ sudo ls -lhd /opt/run/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Nov  4 09:33 /opt/run/
```

For `/opt` both are the same:

```
$ sudo ls -lhd /opt/
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K 2013-06-07 17:15 /opt/
```

However, I don't see how any ancestors beyond the parent directory would affect this?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/opt/run/skyhook/`?  Does `www-data` have execute access to it?

Comment: And similarly, on `/opt/run` and `/opt` itself.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect parent directory permissions.

Comment: Is the `www-data` user in the `skyhook` group? If not, then it doesn't have permission to `chdir()` to `/opt/run/skyhook` or read it... `id -a www-data` to check...

Comment: @twalberg Yes, in fact, that was the problem. Feel free to add an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the updates, it appears that the `/opt/run/skyhook` directory only grants permissions to a) the `skyhook` user, and b) any user that is a member of the `skyhook` group.

On the system where `www-data` cannot access files in the `/opt/run/skyhook` directory, it is most likely the case that `www-data` is not a member of the `skyhook` group, while it does have such membership on the other system.

This can be resolved either by adding `www-data` to the `skyhook` group, or by giving read/execute permissions to the world on `/opt/run/skyhook`, so that it looks similar to the permissions on `/opt/run`.

Comment: A silly mistake, in the end. I'm moving from a largely hand-assembled server to a managed-configuration server, so obscure-yet-important details like this will be codified somewhere!